# File.Copy() and Symbolic Links

Tags: c#, .net, exception, io, symlink

I want to copy a file to a new file name.  Sometimes the source file might be a symbolic (file) link, created with

```
mklink C:\MyPath\ThisIsASymbolicLink.xml C:\MyPath\ThisIsTheOriginal.xml
```

I'm using this code:

```
string from = @"C:\MyPath\ThisIsASymbolicLink.xml";
string to = @"C:\MyPath\WantCopyOfOriginalFileHere.xml";
File.Copy(from, to, true);
```

However, I receive an IOException

> The name of the file cannot be resolved by the system.

when the `from` file is really a symbolic link.

How can I code for the cases where the source file might be a real file, or a symbolic link to a file?

Comment: Hmm, this is a file system mishap.  Something like the link target on another drive that's no longer present.

Comment: @HansPassant: It is all local, on a single drive, and I just created the link this afternoon.

Comment: @HansPassant: This may be related to a similar question I just posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13831759/141172

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Expanding on this [blog post](http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2010/06/getfinalpathnamebyhandle.html), I created extension methods that take a DirectoryInfo or FileInfo that can refer to either an original or a symbolic link, and return a string indicating the fully qualified path name of the original file.

**App Code**

The application code is modified as follows:

```
// Works whether or not file is a symbolic link
string from = 
    new FileInfo(@"C:\MyPath\ThisIsASymbolicLink.xml").GetSymbolicLinkTarget();
```

**Extension Method Code**

```
    private const int FILE_SHARE_READ = 1;
    private const int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2;

    private const int CREATION_DISPOSITION_OPEN_EXISTING = 3;

    private const int FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = 0x02000000;

    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364962%28VS.85%29.aspx
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetFinalPathNameByHandleW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int GetFinalPathNameByHandle(IntPtr handle, [In, Out] StringBuilder path, int bufLen, int flags);

    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFileW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, int dwDesiredAccess, int dwShareMode,
    IntPtr SecurityAttributes, int dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    public static string GetSymbolicLinkTarget(this FileSystemInfo symlink)
    {
        using (SafeFileHandle fileHandle = CreateFile(symlink.FullName, 0, 2, System.IntPtr.Zero, CREATION_DISPOSITION_OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, System.IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            if (fileHandle.IsInvalid)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(512);
            int size = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(fileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), path, path.Capacity, 0);
            if (size < 0)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            // The remarks section of GetFinalPathNameByHandle mentions the return being prefixed with "\\?\"
            // More information about "\\?\" here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=VS.85).aspx
            if (path[0] == '\\' && path[1] == '\\' && path[2] == '?' && path[3] == '\\')
                return path.ToString().Substring(4);
            else
                return path.ToString();
        }
    }
```

**Unit Tests**

```
[TestClass]
public class SymlinkTest
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupFiles()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Temp\SymlinkUnitTest\Original.txt")) throw new Exception("Run Symlinksetup.bat as Admin to create test data.");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OrdinaryFile()
    {
        string file = @"C:\Temp\SymlinkUnitTest\Original.txt";
        string actual = new FileInfo(file).GetSymbolicLinkTarget();
        Assert.IsTrue(actual.EndsWith(@"SymlinkUnitTest\Original.txt"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void FileSymlink()
    {
        string file = @"C:\Temp\SymlinkUnitTest\Symlink.txt";
        string actual = new FileInfo(file).GetSymbolicLinkTarget();
        Assert.IsTrue(actual.EndsWith(@"SymlinkUnitTest\Original.txt"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OrdinaryDirectory()
    {
        string dir = @"C:\Temp\SymlinkUnitTest";
        string actual = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetSymbolicLinkTarget();
        Assert.IsTrue(actual.EndsWith(@"SymlinkUnitTest"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DirectorySymlink()
    {
        string dir = @"C:\Temp\SymlinkUnitTest";
        string actual = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetSymbolicLinkTarget();
        Assert.IsTrue(actual.EndsWith(@"SymlinkUnitTest"));
    }
}
```

**Batch File to Create Unit Test Data**

*Must be run as Administrator... a requirement of mklink.*

```
@Echo Off
Echo Must be run as Administrator (due to mklink)
mkdir C:\Temp
mkdir C:\Temp\SymlinkUnitTest
c:
cd C:\Temp\SymlinkUnitTest

echo Original File>Original.txt
mklink Symlink.txt Original.txt

mklink /D C:\Temp\SymlinkUnitTest\SymDir C:\Temp\SymlinkUnitTest
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this really helped me!  I found an issue, though - SafeFileHandle is disposable and you forgot to use either using() or .dispose().  In my case, I was deleting a symlink after checking the target file's size, and so the file was not actually deleted right away because I was still holding a handle to the file.

Comment: @BigScary: Good catch.  I updated the code.  MSDN started a habit of not including proper coding patterns in their examples that unfortunately some bloggers have carried over.